# Aux Mic to Micro USB Converter

Tags: audio, pi-zero-w, microphone, usb-audio

I have a mic for an aux input that I want to plug into my Pi Zero W. I tried using a micro-USB to aux cable, but it couldn't get the pi to recognize it. Do I need a (micro) USB sound card to record audio using the aux mic, or is this a configuration issue?

Comment: There's NO AUDIO INPUT on ANY model of RPi without extra hardware.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the I/O details of the PI boards are well documented and a simple search would show they have no audio input.